# SQL Server 2008 installation failed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, installation, summary, failed-installation

SQL Server 2008 R2 was installed with an error: "Server installation failed".  Below is the text from the file **Summary.txt**:

```
Overall summary:
  Final result:                  SQL Server installation failed. To
continue, investigate the reason for the failure, correct the problem,
uninstall SQL Server, and then rerun SQL Server Setup.
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2068054013
  Exit facility code:            1212
  Exit error code:               3
  Exit message:                  SQL Server installation failed. To
continue, investigate the reason for the failure, correct the problem,
uninstall SQL Server, and then rerun SQL Server Setup.
  Start time:                    2017-12-08 08:58:00
  End time:                      2017-12-08 09:03:27
  Requested action:              Install
  Log with failure:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
Server\100\Setup
Bootstrap\Log\20171208_085333\SqlSupport_KatmaiRTM_Cpu32_1.log
  Exception help link:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&Ev
tSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=10.50.1600.1

Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  MAILBOOK
  Machine processor count:       1
  OS version:                    Windows 7
  OS service pack:
  OS region:                     United States
  OS language:                   русский (
осс
я

  OS architecture:               x86
  Process architecture:          32 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID
Feature                                  Language             Edition
Version         Clustered

Package properties:
  Description:                   SQL Server Database Services 2008 R2
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2008 R2
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       10
  SPLevel:                       0
  Installation location:         c:\c090d8a68e910260bf\x86\setup\
  Installation edition:          EXPRESS_ADVANCED

User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        Install
  ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      True
  AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
  AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Disabled
  ASBACKUPDIR:                   Backup
  ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
  ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config
  ASDATADIR:                     Data
  ASDOMAINGROUP:                 <empty>
  ASLOGDIR:                      Log
  ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1
  ASSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  ASSVCPASSWORD:                 *****
  ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            <empty>
  ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp
  BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Automatic
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:
  CUSOURCE:
  ENABLERANU:                    True
  ENU:                           True
  ERRORREPORTING:                False
  FARMACCOUNT:                   <empty>
  FARMADMINPORT:                 0
  FARMPASSWORD:                  *****
  FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE,REPLICATION,SSMS,SNAC_SDK
  FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
  FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           <empty>
  FTSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  FTSVCPASSWORD:                 *****
  HELP:                          False
  IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  False
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              False
  INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             <empty>
  INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\SOFTMARINE
  INSTANCEID:                    SOFTMARINE
  INSTANCENAME:                  SOFTMARINE
  ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService
  ISSVCPASSWORD:                 *****
  ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  NPENABLED:                     0
  PASSPHRASE:                    *****
  PCUSOURCE:
  PID:                           *****
  QUIET:                         False
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   False
  ROLE:                          AllFeatures_WithDefaults
  RSINSTALLMODE:                 FilesOnlyMode
  RSSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
  RSSVCPASSWORD:                 *****
  RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  SAPWD:                         *****
  SECURITYMODE:                  <empty>
  SQLBACKUPDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLCOLLATION:                  Cyrillic_General_CI_AS
  SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
  SQLSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic
  SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           MAILBOOK\master
  SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQLUSERDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQMREPORTING:                  False
  TCPENABLED:                    0
  UIMODE:                        AutoAdvance
  X86:                           False

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20171208_085333\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Database Engine Services
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  MSI status:                    Failed: see details below
  MSI error code:                0x3
  MSI log file location:         C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
Server\100\Setup
Bootstrap\Log\20171208_085333\SqlSupport_KatmaiRTM_Cpu32_1.log
  MSI error description:
  MSI status:                    Failed: see details below
  MSI error code:                0x3
  MSI log file location:         C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20171208_085333\sqlncli_Cpu32_1.log
  MSI error description:
  MSI status:                    Failed: see details below
  MSI error code:                0x3
  MSI log file location:         C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20171208_085333\SqlWriter_Cpu32_1.log
  MSI error description:
  MSI status:                    Failed: see details below
  MSI error code:                0x3
  MSI log file location:         C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20171208_085333\SqlSqmShared_Cpu32_1.log
  MSI error description:
  Configuration status:          Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity SDK
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  MSI status:                    Failed: see details below
  MSI error code:                0x3
  MSI log file location:         C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20171208_085333\sqlncli_Cpu32_1.log
  MSI error description:
  Configuration status:          Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Server Replication
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  MSI status:                    Failed: see details below
  MSI error code:                0x3
  MSI log file location:         C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
Server\100\Setup
Bootstrap\Log\20171208_085333\SqlSupport_KatmaiRTM_Cpu32_1.log
  MSI error description:
  Configuration status:          Passed

  Feature:                       Management Tools - Basic
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  MSI status:                    Failed: see details below
  MSI error code:                0x3
  MSI log file location:         C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
Server\100\Setup
Bootstrap\Log\20171208_085333\SqlSupport_KatmaiRTM_Cpu32_1.log
  MSI error description:
  MSI status:                    Failed: see details below
  MSI error code:                0x3
  MSI log file location:         C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20171208_085333\sqlncli_Cpu32_1.log
  MSI error description:
  MSI status:                    Failed: see details below
  MSI error code:                0x3
  MSI log file location:         C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20171208_085333\trin_aide_Cpu32_1.log
  MSI error description:
  MSI status:                    Failed: see details below
  MSI error code:                0x3
  MSI log file location:         C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20171208_085333\SSCESqlWbTools_Cpu32_1.log
  MSI error description:
  MSI status:                    Failed: see details below
  MSI error code:                0x3
  MSI log file location:         C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20171208_085333\SSCRuntime_Cpu32_1.log
  MSI error description:
  MSI status:                    Failed: see details below
  MSI error code:                0x3
  MSI log file location:         C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
Server\100\Setup
Bootstrap\Log\20171208_085333\BestPracticesPolicies_Cpu32_1.log
  MSI error description:
  MSI status:                    Failed: see details below
  MSI error code:                0x3
  MSI log file location:         C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
Server\100\Setup
Bootstrap\Log\20171208_085333\msreportviewer90sp1_Cpu32_1.log
  MSI error description:
  Configuration status:          Passed

Rules with failures:

Global rules:

Scenario specific rules:

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
Server\100\Setup
Bootstrap\Log\20171208_085333\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
```

**Log with failure:**  C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20171208_085333\SqlSupport_KatmaiRTM_Cpu32_1.log:

```
=== Verbose logging started: 08.12.2017  9:03:22  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.7600.00  Calling process: c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\SQLServer2008R2\x86\setup100.exe ===
MSI (c) (04:34) [09:03:22:027]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (04:34) [09:03:22:027]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (04:34) [09:03:22:027]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: c:\c090d8a68e910260bf\1033_ENU_LP\x86\setup\sql2008support\SqlSupport.msi
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (04:34) [09:03:22:027]: Client-side and UI is none or basic: Running entire install on the server.
MSI (c) (04:34) [09:03:22:027]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (04:34) [09:03:22:029]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (04:34) [09:03:22:029]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (04:34) [09:03:22:029]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (14:2C) [09:03:22:035]: Running installation inside multi-package transaction c:\c090d8a68e910260bf\1033_ENU_LP\x86\setup\sql2008support\SqlSupport.msi
MSI (s) (14:2C) [09:03:22:035]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (s) (14:30) [09:03:22:036]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (s) (14:30) [09:03:22:036]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (s) (14:30) [09:03:22:036]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: c:\c090d8a68e910260bf\1033_ENU_LP\x86\setup\sql2008support\SqlSupport.msi
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (s) (14:30) [09:03:22:036]: Note: 1: 2203 2: c:\c090d8a68e910260bf\1033_ENU_LP\x86\setup\sql2008support\SqlSupport.msi 3: -2147287037 
MSI (s) (14:30) [09:03:22:036]: MainEngineThread is returning 3
MSI (s) (14:2C) [09:03:22:037]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (14:2C) [09:03:22:037]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (14:2C) [09:03:22:037]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (14:2C) [09:03:22:037]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (14:2C) [09:03:22:038]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (14:2C) [09:03:22:038]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\InProgress 3: 2 
MSI (s) (14:2C) [09:03:22:038]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\InProgress 3: 2 
MSI (s) (14:2C) [09:03:22:038]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (s) (14:2C) [09:03:22:038]: Restoring environment variables
MSI (c) (04:34) [09:03:22:039]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (04:34) [09:03:22:040]: MainEngineThread is returning 3
=== Verbose logging stopped: 08.12.2017  9:03:22 ===
```

Tell me please, **what could be the problem**? **How can i fix this problem?**

Comment: Looks like the setup is not started in the Admin mode try doing that

Comment: Installation as Admin